# How to change a sentence by another from an array?

Tags: javascript

I made an array and a function that chooses a random word/sentence from that array, but I can't make a function that changes the current word/sentence after clicking a button.

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.setAttribute("id","p1");
var node = document.createTextNode("This is new");
p.appendChild(node);

var parent = document.getElementById("activity");
var child = document.getElementById("description");
parent.replaceChild(,);

// are the things that I know I have to use, but can't apply 
correctly/properly. The button and random word/sentence chooser work just 
fine.
```

Comment: Please post a working example after reading: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - You mentioned _after clicking a button_ with no event handler, you mentioned _replacing word/sentence_ but didn't identify which precisely.

Comment: The words/sentences I was referring to are from an array i created.
ElseButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
 
var anotherAct = getElementById("activity")
var anotherAct = activities[Math.floor(Math.random() * activities.length)];
document.write(anotherAct);
//The else button is already defined elsewhere in the program(css+html)
i already created a general button, but i can't apply the previous function to it in a proper way.